# Error migrating to the New Places SDK Client. 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I am trying to migrate to the New Places SDK Client, however my build.gradle sync fails.

The project works fine until I tried to add the dependency 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0' into my build.gradle.

I receive this error "in The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.2.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies."

build.gradle app

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.csf15taa.finalyearproject"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    //Android Support Design Library
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    //RecyclerView
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    // Support multidex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    // Firebase Core
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    //Firebase Authentication
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    // Firestore Firestore
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
    //Google Map Util, Customer Markers
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    //Google Locations
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    //Google Maps
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    //Places
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'



    // glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

    // Circle ImageView
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

build.gradle project

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven{
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the latest versions of the [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) and [Google](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) libraries:

```
// Firebase Core
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
//Firebase Authentication
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
// Firestore Firestore
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0'
//Google Map Util, Customer Markers
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
//Google Locations
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
//Google Maps
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
//Places
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
```